# Test classes for Visualforce Pages

Tags: visualforce, unit-test

Just wrote my first Visualforce page in Sandbox.  How do I write a test for VF pages using standard controller on Cases?

Comment: Per our Twitter discussion, take a stab at writing a test for your controller extension, using [this thread](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/104/how-should-i-build-test-methods-for-visualforce-controller-extensions) as a starting point, and post your extension & test-class-in-progress here if you get stuck.

Comment: Rachel. If you don't have an apex controller you don't have to write tests.

Answer (score 1):

If you have no extensions, then your page does not require any unit tests. In other words, if your page starts off like this:

```
<apex:page standardController="SomeObject">
    <!-- rest of code -->
```

Then there's nothing to unit test, and you can freely deploy it to production without writing any unit tests. Unit tests are only for Apex Code.